# Arithmetic Parser

Tags: objective-c, parsekit

I am building a parser on top of the [TDArithmeticParser.m](https://github.com/itod/parsekit/blob/master/test/TDArithmeticParser.m) of ParseKit Tests. I extended the [TDArithmeticParserTest.m](https://github.com/itod/parsekit/blob/master/test/TDArithmeticParserTest.m) with the `failing` test:

```
- (void)testMath {
    s = @"10+(2*3)-15";
    result = [p parse:s];
    TDEquals((double)1.0, result); // result == 0.0
}
```

The problem is that I don't understand why the grammar is not working with this test. The corresponding BNF-grammar of the arithmetic parser is:

```
expr           = term (plusTerm | minusTerm)*;
term           = factor (timesFactor | divFactor)*;
plusTerm       = '+' term;
minusTerm      = '-' term;
factor         = phrase exponentFactor | phrase;
timesFactor    = '*' factor;
divFactor      = '/' factor;
exponentFactor = '^' factor;
phrase         = '(' expr ')' | Number;
```

I would be very thankful for any ideas that helps me identifying the problem.

Comment: What is the value of `result`?

Comment: Thx for the hint that the result is missing, Martin. Result is 0.0 what is the result of a nil casted to a double. I updated the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

First, note: `TDArithmeticParser` is just some (not-terribly-robust) sample code included in the test bundle for ParseKit. It is not part of ParseKit itself.

Looks like this is a bug/deficiency in the `TDArithmeticParser` class where `-15` is recognized as **negative fifteen**, not **subtract fifteen**.

If you add whitespace, this issue is resolved:

```
s = @"10+(2*3)- 15";
```

The opposite behavior is also possible with a small change, but then a stand-alone `-15` would not be recognized as valid input (which may or may not be a problem for you).

Both could be supported simultaneously with some changes to the Grammar and the Assembler callbacks.

Comment: But is it really a problem of the TDArithmeticParser? Sadly for me changing the text that I want to parse is not much of a good option. I search for a better solution then to do some kind of "pre-parsing" to prevent this problem to occur.

The BNF-grammar looks fine to me and the code corresponds to the grammar…

Does the parser needs a further setup? I am just using what comes out of [PKParser parser] like the TDArithmeticParser does…